# Can't load PDFKIT - getting a load error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdfkit

I'm trying to set up PDFKit but I can't even run my application to start with. I keep getting this error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- pdfkit (LoadError)
```

Here is my entire application.rb file.

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'pdfkit'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
   Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  #Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Form
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]


    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
    config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware

  end
end
```

I've followed the instructions on the wiki page for pdfkit but I'm bogged with this error. I think it can't find the pdfkit gem but it seems to be installed. Please do help.

Comment: ok I got the path to the pdfkit - now what

Comment: remove `require 'pdfkit'` to the bottom of application.rb

Comment: Done that - still gives me the same error

Comment: Do you use RVM? Can you try to `require 'pdfkit'` in your console (irb, pry, or rails console)?

Comment: require pdfkit in irb returns false now..

Comment: Oh, and you can delete `requre 'pdfkit'` at all, man, if you are using Bundler :). Add to Gemfile `gem 'pdfkit'`, run `bundle` and that's it

Comment: ALl of a sudden its reading false now :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8623/discussion-between-ali-and-fl00r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `require 'pdfkit'` from application.rb

Add to your `Gemfile`

```
gem "pdfkit"
```

And then run `bundle` command from your rails root dir.